# Stable release date for Log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, log4j2

What is the /projected/ GA date for log4j2? I had enough searching but couldnot find any proper information. Our Project is going for GA in FEB 2014 and we are planning for using Log4j2 . Currently we are using logback but after reading more about log4j2 , I understand that log4j has much more to give hence awaiting for the same.

Can anyone please tell me the release date for log4j2 or atleast a guidance of when they are planning to release.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you ask the log4j team on one of their mailing lists?

Update: aiming for summer or fall 2013.

Comment: I have done it now :-) , just thought if anyone at SO can provide the information. Thank you anyways.